# How to create partitionby using parameterized multiple columns in spark by using python?

Tags: python, hadoop, pyspark

I would like to read the multiple columns from paramfile and wanted to pass varialbe into PartitionBy() function.Those i was able to partitionby multiple columns by hardcoding column names.
like:

```py
def save_to_table(dataframe, db_name, tbl_nm):
   dataframe.write.mode("Append").format("parquet").partitionBy("year","month","day").saveAsTable("{}.{}".format(db_name,    tbl_nm))  
   print("Table saved")
```

which is working fine.

but the issue is:
i have tried read from config file and stored all columns name into list like as below

```
pPartitionKey=["year","month","day"]
```

but no idea how to pass list pPartitionKey into PartitionBy() functions.

can anyone help me out in this scenario?

Comment: how will you read from config file using `configparser` library right?

Answer (score 0):

[partitionBy](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html) takes a variable number of columns names as input, but not a list. You can utilize the asterix [*](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/compound_stmts.html#function-definitions) to achieve what you are looking for.

```py
def save_to_table(dataframe, db_name, tbl_nm, pPartitionKey):
   dataframe.write.mode("Append").format("parquet").partitionBy(*pPartitionKey).saveAsTable("{}.{}".format(db_name,    tbl_nm))  
   print("Table saved")
```

Answer (score 0):

store your key in config like

```
[test] // this section is mendatory
pPartitionKey=year,month,day
```

pyspark script

```
import configparser
config = configparser.RawConfigParser()
config.read("config file path")
key = config.get('test','pPartitionKey').split(",")  # read the value from property file and split based on delimiter python will automatically stored into list


dataframe.write.mode("Append").format("parquet").partitionBy(key).saveAsTable("{}.{}".format(db_name,    tbl_nm))
```